# Share this api not updating counter for share buttons using horizontal count

Tags: cakephp, plugins, share, counter, sharethis

I am trying to add Share This plugin in a application done in Cake PHP and I am facing problem with share this button count of each service which I am using in it.

On the Web application , I have used sharethis plugin with horizontal count. When I click on any button from widgets (to share the content) it will increases the count but after refreshing the page it is showing old count itself.

Count for any widgets is not increasing.

Comment: Do you actually share the content (make a tweet, like on Facebook etc)? I assume the plugin shows the actual count after refreshing.

Comment: I am sharing the content using facebook. if before share my link count will be (10) then after share it has to be (11) but after sharing the content if I refresh the page from my site it is showing me (10) as a count it is not increasing share count for site

Comment: Cache issue? Have you tried hard reload (ctrl-f5)? If that doesn't work, we need to see code.

Comment: Yes I have cleared all browser and project cache and after that I have refreshed the page but it is showing old count itself and my share this api code is ""

Comment: <span class="st_facebook_hcount" st_titel = "hi" st_url = "http://crushes.weboapps.com/crushes/message/415743" displayText=""></span>

Comment: you can check it on  http://crushes.weboapps.com/crushes/latest_messages/all page for my site.